# How to remove X first characters of some lines

Tags: php

i want to delete X character of some lines in php. but i have a problem.

for example , i have this :

```
1234,ali
1112,hasan
1555,ahmad
8555,mehdi4
4441,arash
7889,sajad125
1000,mohamad25
```

and now i want to have this :

```
ali
hasan
ahmad
mehdi4
arash
sajad125
mohamad25
```

i just want to remove 5 first characters ,

i also used :

```
echo substr($str,5);
```

but i have a problem. it doesn't work for **LINES** .

Can you help me ?

Comment: You have to loop over each line.

Comment: Are you reading a file?

Comment: @hsz can you give me code please ?

Comment: @user3199050 yes, if it is possible to give a TXT file , that's the thing i need !

Comment: @user3212025 First of all - you should provide us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$t="1234,ali
1112,hasan
1555,ahmad
8555,mehdi4
4441,arash
7889,sajad125
1000,mohamad25";

$r= explode("\n",$t);

foreach ($r as $item) {
    echo substr($item,5)."<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Very Nice , thanks :X

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression replace:

```php
echo preg_replace('~^\d+,~m', '', $string);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/91722)</kbd>

Comment: @user3212025: if you will do huge data replaces, this example is 2x faster than explode()/substr() examples, see [here](https://eval.in/91724) (but still, this is micro-optimization).

Answer (score 0):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$val='1234,ali
1112,hasan
1555,ahmad
8555,mehdi4
4441,arash
7889,sajad125
1000,mohamad25';

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL,$val);
foreach($arr as &$v)
{
$v = substr($v,5);
}

echo "<pre>";

print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ali
    [1] => hasan
    [2] => ahmad
    [3] => mehdi4
    [4] => arash
    [5] => sajad125
    [6] => mohamad25
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) with delimiter `\n` on the contents of the file. This way, you will get an array of strings through which you can loop (and use `substr` for each iteration of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = (you have to set this)
$lines = explode("\n",$string);
$output = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
    $output[] = substr($line,0,5);
}
```

This solution is not for files!

Answer (score 0):

Of course `substr($str,5);` will not work. You need to split the string into multiple lines in order to use it .

```
$string = "1234,ali
1112,hasan
1555,ahmad
8555,mehdi4
4441,arash
7889,sajad125
1000,mohamad25";

$lines = explode("\n", $string);
foreach($lines as $line)
    echo substr($line, 5);
```

As an option you could simply store those values inside the loop in another array and join them at the end with the [implode()](http://php.net/function.implode) function.

Answer (score 0):

It not so beautiful code, but it should work:

```
<?php
$str = '1234,ali
1112,hasan
1555,ahmad
8555,mehdi4
4441,arash
7889,sajad125
1000,mohamad25';
$linesArr = explode('
', $str);
foreach($linesArr as $line) {
    $valuesArr = explode(',', $line);
    echo $valuesArr[1] . '
';
}
?>
```